# Regex - prevent certain string from match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a bank account number.
It can be in this format:
`##########` or `######-##########`

- First group (`######-`), if present, can have 1-6 numbers followed by `-` and all of them can't be zeros. It can match `123456-` but can't `000000-`
- Second group (`##########`) can have 2-10 numbers, there must be one no zero character

I started with this regex `(\d{1,6}\-)?\d{2,10}`. It should match 1. and 2. row, not 3. and 4. This regex matches 1. 2. and 4. How can I exclude 4., meaning prevent matching `000000`?

1. 100000-1234567890
2. 1234567890
3. -1234567890
4. 000000-1234567890

Comment: I added 2 more test cases: `100000-0000000000` (not to match) and `100000-0000000001` (to be matched).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex with a negative lookahead that will make sure the code with all zeros at the start is not matched:

```
^(?:(?!0+-)\d{1,6}-)?(?=\d*[1-9])\d{2,10}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY6kB8/2)

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `(?:(?!0+-)\d{1,6}-)?` - matches *optionally* (one or zero times, due to `(?:...)?` construct) a 1 to 6 digits (with `\d{1,6}`) followed with a hyphen *only* if the digits up to the `-` are not zeros (thanks to the negative lookahead `(?!0+-)`)
- `(?=\d*[1-9])` - the second group of 2 to 10 digits should have at least 1 non-zero digit
- `\d{2,10}` - matches 2 to 10 any digits followed with...
- `$` - end of the string

Basically, you just need two things to add to your regex:

- anchors (`^` and `$`)
- and the lookahead

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use negative lookahead but unsuccessfully. With this example I get it.

Comment: Actually, lookaheads are treacherous, and in most cases they only work together with anchors (`^`/`$`, `\A`/`\Z`/`\z`) and word boundaries (`\b`/`\B`). Glad to help.

Comment: @sln beat me to this, but going from OP: "_Second group (`##########`) can have 2-10 numbers, there must be one no zero character_", so perhaps your regex should be `^(?:(?!0+-)\d{1,6}-)?(?:\d{2,10})?(?<!-0+)$`. As is, it matches things like `100000-000000000`. (second group all zeroes)

Comment: Ok, there was no test case for that, fixed and added two test cases.

Answer (score 1):

The Wiktof Stribizew's answer is "the" good one.
But if you want to avoid headaches with lookahead you can merely use this:

```
^(?:[1-9](?:\d{1,5})?-)?\d{2,10}$
```

Here we simply forbid an initial "0" in the first group, then allow only till 5 other digits.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oL9fQ1/2).